# Cannot see the extension name in admin configuration in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I had created the file 
`Labwise_Findhospital.xml` and added in `app/etc/Labwise_Findhospital.xml` but i cannot see the name in the admin configuration.

Can anyone suggest me.

I need to clear soon

Comment: just check in your xml file at the start of the first line check is their any spaces.if yes please remove it and save and check and clear cache

Comment: from your post in the file called app/etc/Labwise_Findhospital.xml their is space in the first line

Comment: No.there is no space when i tried in test server it has worked fine.But the issue is getting after copying to live.

Comment: app/etc/Labwise_Findhospital.xml   change the location of file  to app/etc/modules/Labwise_Findhospital.xml  
i checked by myself it is working

Comment: i copied but it is not showing in admin configuration page.

Comment: refresh and disable you cache then check it. now what is your configuration file path?

Comment: module configuration file path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23312/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-annaram-ravinder).

Answer (score 1):

[image]
**app/etc/Labwise_Findhospital.xml** change the location of file to **app/etc/modules/Labwise_Findhospital.xml** i checked by myself it is working on my side..

Comment: yes i got it.Now it is showing thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are using incorrect directory names. In your example you say that file path to your extension is app/code/local/labwise/findhospital/. But you called it Labwise_Findhospital. In this case, you should rename your directories to app/code/local/Labwise/Findhospital/ (starting from capital letter)